# $\bar{x}$ notation in Field Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, notation, extension-field

in my lecture about field extension and tower theorem for extension degree, the professor gives the following example :

---

$$\mathbb{Z}_2 \le \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^2 + x + 1)} \le \frac{(\frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^2 + x + 1)})[y]}{(y^3 + y + 1)} $$ has degree $3 * 2 = 6$, and a basis consists of $$1, \bar{x},\bar{y}, \bar{xy}, \bar{y^2}, \overline{xy^2}$$

This finite field thus has $2^6 $ elements.

---

It is the very first time he uses the notation $\bar{x}$ with this horizontal bar above $x$ and I can't understand what it means. Is it an arbitrary root of the poly $x^2 + x + 1$ ? Can someone explain ? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably used for "representatives". The fields are constructed through a quotient, so $y$ is technically not an element of the field, but it is in an equivalence class, so $\overline y$ represents that equivalence class. But you need more context to make sure. Why not ask the professor yourself?

Comment: this is very common notation for reresentatives

Comment: The elements of a factor ring $R/I$ are cosets $\overline{x}=x+I$. Here $R=K[x]$ first, and then a polynomial ring in $y$. Costes are very often denoted by a bar. For example $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z=\{\overline{0},\overline{1}\}$.